# Wordpress navigation before specific items

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I am using ACF and the `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter to add specific classes to items. For instance `buttons` get a `.btn` class, items that need an icon before it get an `icon` class, etc. I have figured out an easy way to add text and items within the `<a>`, but I can't figure out how to add BEFORE the actual `<a>` tag within the `<li>` tag. I know there is an easy function

```
wp_nav_menu( array ( 'before' => '<span>I am adding before the <li></span>' ) );
```

However, this does not work for me since I only need the `<span>` before specific items, depending on the ACF field. I also know I could potentially use wordpress walker feature, but I'd like to avoid that since it something pretty small I'm trying to do.

Here is my filter for `wp_nav_menu_objects`

```
function add_menu_item_type( $items, $args ) {
    $parents = wp_list_pluck( $items, 'menu_item_parent' );
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $args->menu );

    foreach ( $items as &$item ) {
        $type = get_field( 'menu_item_type', $item );
        $icon = get_field( 'menu_item_icon', $item );
        $show_on_mobile = get_field( 'show_on_mobile', $item );
        $mobile_nav = get_field( 'include_in_mobile_nav', $menu );

        if ( 'logo' === $type ) {
            array_push( $item->classes, 'logo' );
        }

        if ( 'button' === $type ) {
            array_push( $item->classes, 'btn d-none d-lg-flex' );
        } elseif ( ! $show_on_mobile && ( 'primary_left_nav' === $args->theme_location || 'primary_right_nav' === $args->theme_location ) ) {
            array_push( $item->classes, 'd-none d-lg-block' );
        }

        if ( $mobile_nav || 'primary_mobile_nav' === $args->theme_location ) {
            array_push( $item->classes, 'col-24' );
        }

        // If Dropdown add class.
        if ( 'dropdown' === $type ) {
            $item->title .= ' <span class="icon icon-arrow-down-thin"></span>';
        }

        // If Dropdown add class.
        if ( 'icon' === $type && ! empty( $icon ) ) {
            // HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE $item->before
            $item->title = '<span class="icon icon-' . $icon . '"></span> ' . $item->title;
        }

        // If Dropdown and has children.
        if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents, true ) && 'has-children' === $item->classes[0] && 'dropdown' === $type ) {
            array_push( $item->classes, 'menu-item-dropdown' );
        }
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_item_type', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Why you need to coding for WordPress navigation, even you can add class and icon with the admin section very easily.

Comment: @Jamie, would using the CSS `before` pseudo-selector in combination with `content` not help? It's not clear what you need to insert before the span